# RMagick convert problem

Tags: rmagick

In linux i'm doing the below to convert a multipage PDF into images resized and with a high resolution:

```
convert -verbose -colorspace RGB -resize 800 -interlace none -density 300 -quality 80 test.pdf test.jpg
```

For the life of me, i can't seem to reproduce this EXACT command using RMagick. I tried something like this below but the image doesn't have the size/resolution i want. Any ideas?

```
Magick::ImageList.new('test.pdf').each_with_index { |img, i|
  img.resize_to_fit!(800, 800)
  img.write("test-#{i}.jpg") {
    self.quality = 80
    self.density = '300'
    self.colorspace = Magick::RGBColorspace
    self.interlace = Magick::NoInterlace
  }
}
```

Cheers,
G.

Comment: FOUND the solution. You have to use: img = Magick::Image::read('test.pdf') { self.density = 300 }.each { |img| # blah }
This basically reads in the file with the specified density.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use block with quality options for method `new` instead of method `write`:

```
Magick::ImageList.new('test.pdf') do
  self.quality = 80
  self.density = '300'
  self.colorspace = Magick::RGBColorspace
  self.interlace = Magick::NoInterlace
end.each_with_index do |img, i|
  img.resize_to_fit!(800, 800)
  img.write("test-#{i}.jpg")
end
```

Not sure actually about `colorspace` and `interlace` options,
but it definitely works for `quality` and `density`.

Comment: Yeah, its not working for colorspace. Is there any way for colorspace change as well?