# Low quality when converting PDF to JPG

Tags: ruby, pdf, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm attempting to use Imagemagic(RMAgick) to convert PDF-document into image. Original PDF is created from an image too(not native vector PDF).

```
image = Magick::Image::from_blob(original_pdf) { self.format = 'PDF' }
image[0].format = 'JPG'
image[0].to_blob
image[0].write(to_file.jpg) {
  self.quality = 100
  self.density = 144
}
```

But resulting image has too low quality, when printing. Original PDF has good quality in same time. 
I'm trying to use these options

```
self.quality = 100
self.density = 144
```

or using PNG rather JPG, but all this doesn't work, only increase image size in kb ).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert PDF to image with high resolution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605006/convert-pdf-to-image-with-high-resolution)

Answer (score 9):

Assuming `original_pdf` is content of pdf file, e.g.:

```
original_pdf = File.open('from_file.pdf', 'rb').read
```

Then apply quality options in block of method `from_blob`
instead of block of method `write`:

```
image = Magick::Image::from_blob(original_pdf) do
  self.format = 'PDF'
  self.quality = 100
  self.density = 144
end
image[0].format = 'JPG'
image[0].to_blob
image[0].write('to_file.jpg')
```

Look also [quality options for `Magick::ImageList.new` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631543/rmagick-convert-problem/20586384#20586384).

Comment: Yes! this is the only way that actually seems to make the density have any effect